# Django ORM format date and check if less or equal to

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm using Django 1.5. I have created a generic function to fetch data from Database using ORM
Currently I'm passing dictionary to this function to filter data. See the code below

```
objTable.objects.values(*listArg).filter(**dictFilter)
```

This working fine. Now i have a datetime field in one of the table. And i need to compare this against a date so i need a query like below

```
where DATE(start_date)<= '2013-08-08'
```

Currently to check if the date less than or equal i will be passing a dictionary like

```
{'start_date__lte':datetime.date.today()}
```

Since 'start_date'  is a datetimefield its stores value like '2013-08-07 00:00:00' How can i format this field then use less than or equal ?

Comment: Do you want generate `{'start_date__lte':'2013-08-08'}` from `start_date`, `lte`, '2013-08-08`?

Comment: Yes 'start_date' is a datetime field and its stores value like '2013-08-07 00:00:00' . and I need to compare this against datetime.date.today() like {'start_date__lte':datetime.date.today()} But it does not seems to work

Comment: You should accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a string like '2013-08-08' instead use a python date object, you can convert a string to a date with something like

```
import datetime

{'start_date__lte': datetime.datetime.strptime('2013-08-08', '%Y-%m-%d').date()}
```

Comment: Thanks. Acutaly i'm using datetime.date.today() instead of string.I have updated by question. Sorry for the confusion. My issue its that start_date is a date time field so values are stored as 2013-08-07 00:00:00 . So i believe that it is not comparing against datetime.date.today().

Answer (score 0):

Generate `datetime` from `date` object using [datetime.combine](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
{'start_date__lte': datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time())}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe that you can simply do this. if you want to compare to today at realtime.

```
import datetime
{'start_date__lte':datetime.datetime.now()}
```